# Using ng-repeat when json data is modified by ng-change

Tags: json, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

[**PLUNKER**](http://plnkr.co/edit/XXJ0CxHZUkrz5OHAY6ri?p=preview)

The data which is rendered via ng-repeat before any changes in JSON data, this works fine. There is a select box, and on-change of the select box option the json data gets modified. I need to render the html using the new data.

```
<div class="col-sm-12" ng-controller="treeGridController">
    <div class="event-mob-tree-box" ng-repeat="data in tree_data">
        <div class="event-mob-tree-content">
            <div class="event-tree-log">
                <p>Items: <span class="event-tree-log-result">{{data.Items}}</span>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="sub-event-mob">
            <select ng-model="selectItem" ng-options="c.DemographicId as c.Name for c in data.children track by c.DemographicId" ng-change="loadSubEvents(selectItem)">
                <option value="">--Choose Subevents--</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the html with modified JSON data, this isn't working

```
<div class="col-sm-12" ng-controller="treeGridController">
    <div class="event-mob-tree-box" ng-repeat="tree in newTree">
        <div class="event-mob-tree-content">
            <div class="event-tree-log">
                <p>Items: <span class="event-tree-log-result">{{tree.Items}}</span>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="sub-event-mob">
            <select ng-model="selectItem" ng-options="c.DemographicId as c.Name for c in tree.children track by c.DemographicId" ng-change="loadSubEvents(selectItem)">
                <option value="">--Choose Subevents--</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Controller :

```
angular.module('MainApp')
.controller('treeGridController', function ($scope, $timeout, $http) {
var tree;
var id = 1;
var rawTreeData = [];
var newTree = [];
var obj;
$scope.tree_data = [];
var Recurse = function (data, parentId) {
    angular.forEach(data, function (items) {
        id++;
        obj = {
            "DemographicId": id,
                "ParentId": parentId,
                "Name": items.Name,
                "Items": items.ItemsCount,
                "Failed": items.ItemsFailedCount,
                "Execution": (new Date(items.ExecutionEnd) - new Date(items.ExecutionStart)) / 1000,
                "Actions": items.Actions
        };
        rawTreeData.push(obj);
        if (angular.isObject(items.Suscribers) || angular.isObject(items.Events)) {
            Recurse(items.Suscribers || items.Events, id);
        }

    });
};

$http.get('http://dev.appgile.com/monitor/api/eventlog/geteventlog')
    .then(function (res) {
    $scope.datas = res.data;
    angular.forEach(res.data, function (items) {
        obj = {
            "DemographicId": id,
                "ParentId": null,
                "Name": items.Name,
                "Items": items.ItemsCount,
                "Failed": items.ItemsFailedCount,
                "Execution": (new Date(items.ExecutionEnd) - new Date(items.ExecutionStart)) / 1000,
                "Actions": items.Actions
        };
        rawTreeData.push(obj);
        if (angular.isObject(items.Suscribers) || angular.isObject(items.Events)) {
            Recurse(items.Suscribers || items.Events, id);
        }
        id++;
    });

    var myTreeData = getTree(rawTreeData, 'DemographicId', 'ParentId');

    $scope.tree_data = myTreeData;
    console.log(JSON.stringify(myTreeData));


    /*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

    function processChildren(item, ret, parent) {
        for (var i = 0; i < item.length; i++) {
            var cur = item[i];
            var DemId = cur.DemographicId;
            ret.push({
                "DemographicId": DemId,
                    "parent": parent,
                    "ParentId": cur.parentId,
                    "Name": cur.Name,
                    "Items": cur.Items,
                    "Failed": cur.Failed,
                    "Execution": cur.Execution,
                    "Actions": cur.Actions,
                    "Children": cur.children
            });
            if ("children" in cur && cur.children.length > 0) {
                processChildren(cur.children, ret, DemId);
            }
        }
    }

    var processedTree = [];

    processChildren(myTreeData, processedTree, null);
    $scope.loadSubEvents = function (item) {
        for (var i = 0; i < processedTree.length; i++) {
            if (processedTree[i].DemographicId == item) {
                //console.log(processedTree[i]);
                $scope.newTree = processedTree[i];
                console.log($scope.newTree.Name);
                //return newTree
            }
        }
    }
});
});
```

Console Log for `tree_data`

```
{"DemographicId":1,"ParentId":null,"Name":"Subscriber","Items":5,"Failed":6,"Execution":0,"Actions":[{"Name":"Start","Text":"Abc","IconFileName":"file","ToolTip":"xyz","IsVisible":false,"IsEnabled":true,"IsForbidden":false,"ActionUrl":null,"CommandName":"ijk"},{"Name":"Start","Text":"Abc","IconFileName":"file","ToolTip":"xyz","IsVisible":false,"IsEnabled":true,"IsForbidden":false,"ActionUrl":null,"CommandName":"ijk"}],"children":[{"DemographicId":2,"ParentId":1,"Name":"Suscriber 1","Items":20,"Failed":10,"Execution":0,"Actions":null,"children":[{"DemographicId":3,"ParentId":2,"Name":"Subscriber","Items":5,"Failed":6,"Execution":0,"Actions":[{"Name":"Start","Text":"Abc","IconFileName":"file","ToolTip":"xyz","IsVisible":false,"IsEnabled":true,"IsForbidden":false,"ActionUrl":null,"CommandName":"ijk"},{"Name":"Start","Text":"Abc","IconFileName":"file","ToolTip":"xyz","IsVisible":false,"IsEnabled":true,"IsForbidden":false,"ActionUrl":null,"CommandName":"ijk"}],"children":[{"DemographicId":4,"ParentId":3,"Name":"Suscriber 1","Items":20,"Failed":10,"Execution":0,"Actions":null},{"DemographicId":5,"ParentId":3,"Name":"Suscriber 1","Items":20,"Failed":10,"Execution":0,"Actions":null}]},{"DemographicId":6,"ParentId":2,"Name":"Subscriber","Items":5,"Failed":6,"Execution":0,"Actions":[{"Name":"Start","Text":"Abc","IconFileName":"file","ToolTip":"xyz","IsVisible":false,"IsEnabled":true,"IsForbidden":false,"ActionUrl":null,"CommandName":"ijk"},{"Name":"Start","Text":"Abc","IconFileName":"file","ToolTip":"xyz","IsVisible":false,"IsEnabled":true,"IsForbidden":false,"ActionUrl":null,"CommandName":"ijk"}],"children":[{"DemographicId":7,"ParentId":6,"Name":"Suscriber 1","Items":20,"Failed":10,"Execution":0,"Actions":null},{"DemographicId":8,"ParentId":6,"Name":"Suscriber 1","Items":20,"Failed":10,"Execution":0,"Actions":null}]}]},{"DemographicId":9,"ParentId":1,"Name":"Suscriber 1","Items":20,"Failed":10,"Execution":0,"Actions":null,"children":[{"DemographicId":10,"ParentId":9,"Name":"Subscriber","Items":5,"Failed":6,"Execution":0,"Actions":[{"Name":"Start","Text":"Abc","IconFileName":"file","ToolTip":"xyz","IsVisible":false,"IsEnabled":true,"IsForbidden":false,"ActionUrl":null,"CommandName":"ijk"},{"Name":"Start","Text":"Abc","IconFileName":"file","ToolTip":"xyz","IsVisible":false,"IsEnabled":true,"IsForbidden":false,"ActionUrl":null,"CommandName":"ijk"}],"children":[{"DemographicId":11,"ParentId":10,"Name":"Suscriber 1","Items":20,"Failed":10,"Execution":0,"Actions":null},{"DemographicId":12,"ParentId":10,"Name":"Suscriber 1","Items":20,"Failed":10,"Execution":0,"Actions":null}]},{"DemographicId":13,"ParentId":9,"Name":"Subscriber","Items":5,"Failed":6,"Execution":0,"Actions":[{"Name":"Start","Text":"Abc","IconFileName":"file","ToolTip":"xyz","IsVisible":false,"IsEnabled":true,"IsForbidden":false,"ActionUrl":null,"CommandName":"ijk"},{"Name":"Start","Text":"Abc","IconFileName":"file","ToolTip":"xyz","IsVisible":false,"IsEnabled":true,"IsForbidden":false,"ActionUrl":null,"CommandName":"ijk"}],"children":[{"DemographicId":14,"ParentId":13,"Name":"Suscriber 1","Items":20,"Failed":10,"Execution":0,"Actions":null},{"DemographicId":15,"ParentId":13,"Name":"Suscriber 1","Items":20,"Failed":10,"Execution":0,"Actions":null}]}]}]},{"DemographicId":16,"ParentId":null,"Name":"Subscriber","Items":5,"Failed":6,"Execution":0,"Actions":[{"Name":"Start","Text":"Abc","IconFileName":"file","ToolTip":"xyz","IsVisible":false,"IsEnabled":true,"IsForbidden":false,"ActionUrl":null,"CommandName":"ijk"},{"Name":"Start","Text":"Abc","IconFileName":"file","ToolTip":"xyz","IsVisible":false,"IsEnabled":true,"IsForbidden":false,"ActionUrl":null,"CommandName":"ijk"}],"children":[{"DemographicId":17,"ParentId":16,"Name":"Suscriber 1","Items":20,"Failed":10,"Execution":0,"Actions":null,"children":[{"DemographicId":18,"ParentId":17,"Name":"Subscriber","Items":5,"Failed":6,"Execution":0,"Actions":[{"Name":"Start","Text":"Abc","IconFileName":"file","ToolTip":"xyz","IsVisible":false,"IsEnabled":true,"IsForbidden":false,"ActionUrl":null,"CommandName":"ijk"},{"Name":"Start","Text":"Abc","IconFileName":"file","ToolTip":"xyz","IsVisible":false,"IsEnabled":true,"IsForbidden":false,"ActionUrl":null,"CommandName":"ijk"}],"children":[{"DemographicId":19,"ParentId":18,"Name":"Suscriber 1","Items":20,"Failed":10,"Execution":0,"Actions":null},{"DemographicId":20,"ParentId":18,"Name":"Suscriber 1","Items":20,"Failed":10,"Execution":0,"Actions":null}]},{"DemographicId":21,"ParentId":17,"Name":"Subscriber","Items":5,"Failed":6,"Execution":0,"Actions":[{"Name":"Start","Text":"Abc","IconFileName":"file","ToolTip":"xyz","IsVisible":false,"IsEnabled":true,"IsForbidden":false,"ActionUrl":null,"CommandName":"ijk"},{"Name":"Start","Text":"Abc","IconFileName":"file","ToolTip":"xyz","IsVisible":false,"IsEnabled":true,"IsForbidden":false,"ActionUrl":null,"CommandName":"ijk"}],"children":[{"DemographicId":22,"ParentId":21,"Name":"Suscriber 1","Items":20,"Failed":10,"Execution":0,"Actions":null},{"DemographicId":23,"ParentId":21,"Name":"Suscriber 1","Items":20,"Failed":10,"Execution":0,"Actions":null}]}]},{"DemographicId":24,"ParentId":16,"Name":"Suscriber 1","Items":20,"Failed":10,"Execution":0,"Actions":null,"children":[{"DemographicId":25,"ParentId":24,"Name":"Subscriber","Items":5,"Failed":6,"Execution":0,"Actions":[{"Name":"Start","Text":"Abc","IconFileName":"file","ToolTip":"xyz","IsVisible":false,"IsEnabled":true,"IsForbidden":false,"ActionUrl":null,"CommandName":"ijk"},{"Name":"Start","Text":"Abc","IconFileName":"file","ToolTip":"xyz","IsVisible":false,"IsEnabled":true,"IsForbidden":false,"ActionUrl":null,"CommandName":"ijk"}],"children":[{"DemographicId":26,"ParentId":25,"Name":"Suscriber 1","Items":20,"Failed":10,"Execution":0,"Actions":null},{"DemographicId":27,"ParentId":25,"Name":"Suscriber 1","Items":20,"Failed":10,"Execution":0,"Actions":null}]},{"DemographicId":28,"ParentId":24,"Name":"Subscriber","Items":5,"Failed":6,"Execution":0,"Actions":[{"Name":"Start","Text":"Abc","IconFileName":"file","ToolTip":"xyz","IsVisible":false,"IsEnabled":true,"IsForbidden":false,"ActionUrl":null,"CommandName":"ijk"},{"Name":"Start","Text":"Abc","IconFileName":"file","ToolTip":"xyz","IsVisible":false,"IsEnabled":true,"IsForbidden":false,"ActionUrl":null,"CommandName":"ijk"}],"children":[{"DemographicId":29,"ParentId":28,"Name":"Suscriber 1","Items":20,"Failed":10,"Execution":0,"Actions":null},{"DemographicId":30,"ParentId":28,"Name":"Suscriber 1","Items":20,"Failed":10,"Execution":0,"Actions":null}]}]}]}
```

Console Log for `newTree`

```
{"DemographicId":2,"parent":1,"Name":"Suscriber 1","Items":20,"Failed":10,"Execution":0,"Actions":null,"Children":[{"DemographicId":3,"ParentId":2,"Name":"Subscriber","Items":5,"Failed":6,"Execution":0,"Actions":[{"Name":"Start","Text":"Abc","IconFileName":"file","ToolTip":"xyz","IsVisible":false,"IsEnabled":true,"IsForbidden":false,"ActionUrl":null,"CommandName":"ijk"},{"Name":"Start","Text":"Abc","IconFileName":"file","ToolTip":"xyz","IsVisible":false,"IsEnabled":true,"IsForbidden":false,"ActionUrl":null,"CommandName":"ijk"}],"children":[{"DemographicId":4,"ParentId":3,"Name":"Suscriber 1","Items":20,"Failed":10,"Execution":0,"Actions":null},{"DemographicId":5,"ParentId":3,"Name":"Suscriber 1","Items":20,"Failed":10,"Execution":0,"Actions":null}]},{"DemographicId":6,"ParentId":2,"Name":"Subscriber","Items":5,"Failed":6,"Execution":0,"Actions":[{"Name":"Start","Text":"Abc","IconFileName":"file","ToolTip":"xyz","IsVisible":false,"IsEnabled":true,"IsForbidden":false,"ActionUrl":null,"CommandName":"ijk"},{"Name":"Start","Text":"Abc","IconFileName":"file","ToolTip":"xyz","IsVisible":false,"IsEnabled":true,"IsForbidden":false,"ActionUrl":null,"CommandName":"ijk"}],"children":[{"DemographicId":7,"ParentId":6,"Name":"Suscriber 1","Items":20,"Failed":10,"Execution":0,"Actions":null},{"DemographicId":8,"ParentId":6,"Name":"Suscriber 1","Items":20,"Failed":10,"Execution":0,"Actions":null}]}]}
```

Comment: What are the console.logs showing for tree_data and newTree ?

Comment: @Okazari : I don't know if this is the right way to do it or should I be using directives?

Comment: I'm pretty sure we can solve this without any custom directives. Could your precise one thing ? I don't really understand if the two HTML parts are the same or at different places ?

Comment: @Okazari : These are two different divs on the same html page.

Comment: @Okazari : Here's the plunk. http://plnkr.co/edit/XXJ0CxHZUkrz5OHAY6ri?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty sure i found the issue ([working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/uUv0wwxuCG9XoVS6Wque?p=preview)) :

You are using two instances of the controller :

```
ng-controller="treeGridController"
```

This will create an instance of treeGridController. The newTree var you were modifying was not in the same controller.

I moved the ng-controller on a upper div (global for the two list) and it almost worked.

The `scope.newTree = processedTree[i];` was also giving an object instead of an array. You could do this like this : `scope.newTree = [processedTree[i]];`

I'm not exactly sure of how the global thing should behave but you can at least go further from now

Hope it helped.

Comment: Wow, that was so dumb of me. Thank you.

Comment: @AmitSingh This kind of mistakes can be really hard to find by yourself tho.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if something like this would help

HTML

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MainCtrl as mainCtrl">
  <div>
    <select name='options' ng-change='mainCtrl.modificarArray();' ng-model="mainCtrl.value;">
  <option value='1'>Option 1</option>
  <option value='2'>Option 2</option>
  <option value='3'>Option 3</option>
</select>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div ng-repeat="item in mainCtrl.lista">{{item.nombre}}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.controller("MainCtrl", MainCtrl);

function MainCtrl(){
  var vm = this;
  vm.value = 1;
  vm.modificarArray = modificarArray;

  function modificarArray(){
    vm.lista[vm.value].nombre = "changed";
  }

  vm.lista = [
    {nombre:'nombre01', apellido:'apellido01'},
    {nombre:'nombre02', apellido:'apellido02'},
    {nombre:'nombre03', apellido:'apellido03'},
    {nombre:'nombre04', apellido:'apellido04'},
    {nombre:'nombre05', apellido:'apellido05'}
  ];
}
```

http://codepen.io/arielcessario/pen/qdgMYN?editors=101

Regards!!

Comment: This is a nice attempt, but unfortunately won't work in my case.